# remove the numbers from txt file

Tags: python, numbers, rs

I have this rs.txt file containing:

> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41342447=AG rs41367249=AG (312, 0.207447)
>
> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41342447=AG rs41444944=AG (310, 0.206117)
>
> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41342447=AG (422, 0.280585)
>
> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41483646=AG (384, 0.255319)
>
> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41369844=AG rs235633=CT (301, 0.200133)
>
> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41369844=AG (396, 0.263298)
>
> rs41453844=CT rs36005134=AT rs41518851=AG rs2287980=GT rs28526632=AG rs41440845=CT (384, 0.255319)

Can anyone help me with python codes to remove the numbers in the brackets? I just want the rs# to be saved in a new .txt file. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem that has never been solved earlier.  Could you at least attempt _something_?

Comment: If you wish that others perform the task for you, then consider posting it at oDesk or freelancer instead.

Comment: It is very hard to help with code that is not posted... Note that SO is not a good place for "teach me language XXX from start" or "write code for me now!" questions.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone. I'm a newbie and zero in python. I've tried to do this using regex but it doesn't work. Thanks for all your advice. In the next time I posted here, I'll do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
line = line.split("(")[0]
```

(everything preceding the first `(` character)

so your program is something like

```
with open("rs.txt") as inf, open("new.txt", "w") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.split("(", 1)[0].rstrip() + "\n"
        outf.write(line)
```